# NSURLconnection and json

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsurlconnection

i know this is a stupid question but i d'ont know how to do that. from this link  [the           requested link](http://www.goalzz.com/main.aspx?region=-1&area=6&update=true) is possible to return json data with NSURLconnection ? I hope some one  check this link and tell me if is this possible because i am new in this stuff.

EDIT:

i tried with **NSJSONSerialization**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.goalzz.com/main.aspx?region=-1&area=6&update=true"]];
    connectionData = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 }
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    Data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [Data appendData:data];
}

 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:Data options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

if (jsonParsingError) {
    NSLog(@"JSON ERROR: %@", [jsonParsingError localizedDescription]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"OBJECT: %@", [object class]);
}
}
```

and I get this error message in the console :

**JSON ERROR:** The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)

Comment: First of all, that URL doesn't return JSON. Second, NSURLConnection doesn't provide a built-in JSON parser so you'll have to use a third party library for that. [TouchJSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON) is one option.

Comment: thank you @Anton Holmquist.so with ToushJSON i can retrieve data an parse it?.

Comment: No. Think of fetching the data and parsing it as two separate tasks. First fetch it using NSURLConnection or any other request library, then parse it using TouchJSON or any other parse library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the comment above suggests, that link doesn't return JSON.  However, assuming you do have such a link, you can use the NSJSONSerialization class to parse JSON data into objective-C classes:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010946

Combine this with NSURLConnection and you can do what you ask.  Here's a walk through on implementing NSURLConnection:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE

And here's an outline of what you'd need. Obviously this is not working code:

```
- (void)downloadJSONFromURL {
    NSURLRequest *request = ....
    NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
    // ...
}

NSMutableData *urlData;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    urlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [urlData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
    id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

    if (jsonParsingError) {
        DLog(@"JSON ERROR: %@", [jsonParsingError localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        DLog(@"OBJECT: %@", [object class]);
    }
}
```